# Getting the default credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation, credentials

I have page `A.aspx` in my domain

this page (in its c# codes)  makes a request to another page.(`B.aspx`). - which is in my domain also

the whole site is in **windows** authentication

```
HttpWebRequest loHttp = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mydom.com/b.aspx");
loHttp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
loHttp.Timeout = 100000;
HttpWebResponse loWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)loHttp.GetResponse();
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");  // Windows default Code Page
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(loWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
string lcHtml = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
loWebResponse.Close();
loResponseStream.Close();
return lcHtml;
```

Im using impersonation in my web site to a specific account.

the account is being transferred by the statement :

```
 loHttp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

all is fine.....

However, I want to see those credentials ( I need their "get")

I know that the current thread account(being affected by impersonation)is given by :

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

but I want to see the values that in the **UseDefaultCredentials** !
something like

```
DefaultCredentials.getCurrent.username
DefaultCredentials.getCurrent.password...
```

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to do this but in WinForms. It might be work for you too:

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

or

```
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

Comment: Does CredentialCache is like defaultcredentials ?

Comment: He's correct, the static property DefaultCredentials is what the framework is using internally when you set UseDefaultCredentials to true.